# Unable to find PHPUnit code coverage stats

Tags: plugins, testing, unit-tests

Where should I check for the code coverage stats when using PHPUnit for WordPress?

**My WordPress setup**:

I have setup WordPress using [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) and my testing suite includes [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit#installation) and [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/#install).

**How I executed test cases to find code coverage?**

When I execute `phpunit` command to test a WordPress plugin, I'm able to see, if the test cases passed or failed. In my case there were *no failures*.

*To find the code coverage*, I executed `phpunit --coverage-text=./coverage.txt`, the test cases passed but I'm unable to find the coverage.txt file to check the actual code coverage stats.

A search for `coverage.txt` file in plugin's folder using the Windows explorer returned no results. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have the xdebug PHP extension enabled. When I run the tests without xdebug enabled on PHPUnit 4.8.26, I get this message:

> Warning:        The Xdebug extension is not loaded
>
> No code coverage will be generated.

It looks like VVV comes with xdebug though, so it is probably enabled by default. But perhaps you disabled it somehow?

To check if xdebug is enabled you can run `php --ri xdebug`. That should show you the xdebug settings, if the extension is currently enabled.

If the extension *is* enabled, then maybe you haven't [configured a `whitelist`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.whitelisting-files) within your configuration file. Take a look at those docs if you haven't already, as they outline the steps needed to generate code coverage data with PHPUnit.